# Special vehicle list in GTA 5

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

So i was wondering, what happens if you lose a special vehicle like if it was destroyed or something, can you take another one in the garage or buy the DLC again. ( i know this may be a silly question but i really curious )

Comment: *DLC* ? You mean the add-ons/mods you buy for a car, right ?

Comment: No i mean in single player you don't buy the DLC cars you get it instantly, so what happens if i take the car out for a ride then lose it or destroyed can i get another one in the special vehicle list ?

Comment: I'm so sorry, i am new to this site i didn't know it was the same question. again im sorry.